# coded ui waitforcontrolready not working on VSTT2013 but worked on VSTT2010

Tags: coded-ui-tests, visual-studio-2013

I meet the following issues after migration from VSTT2010 to 2013:
all my ....`WaitForControlReady(3000);` throw exception object reference not defined to object reference

e.g:
`UIMap.UIIdentificationWindowWindow.UIIdentificationDocument4.WaitForControlReady(3000);`
Is waiting for a popup to be displayed

`MonNavigateur.WaitForControlReady();`
with:
`public static BrowserWindow MonNavigateur;` declared in the class
and: `MonNavigateur = BrowserWindow.Launch(new Uri(sAppConfigExtranetUri));` in MyTestInitialize() method

I worked like a charm in VSTT2010 ;(

The temporary workaround used is to replace all my `WaitForControlReady();` with a not satisfying `Playback.Wait(x000);`

Anyone has an idea to solve this problem please?

Comment: What type of exception? NullReferenceException?

Comment: What version of the preview do you have?  I'd wager that, if it's not ultimate, that coded ui isn't supported in your version.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you upgrade your reference assemblies to the latest version.  WaitForControlReady() should be a part of the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting` assembly.  Version 12.0 would be required to run in VS2013.